# How to get GuzzleHttp 7.x resolved request url from response

Tags: php, httpclient, guzzle

How to get the URI/URL of the request sent, from the response?

```
<?php

// Create a client with a base URI
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://example.com/api/']);
// Send a request to https://example.com/api/test
$response = $client->request('GET', 'test');

// I want the following line to print 'https://example.com/api/test'
var_export( $response->getUrl() );
```

**Note:** I want something like the last line of the above snippet to work.